# Promise.all not waiting for final result

Tags: javascript, async-await

Currently I am having a small issue when dealing with promises. Basicly I have a nested map where inside I have a fetch request. The results I am getting back are correct, but I want to have a loading state, need to know when the requests are over. Currently my implementation is as following:

```
const countries = ['de', 'pt', 'en']
const market = ['test1', 'test2']


countries.map(async c => {
  const promises = market.map(m => {
    return fetch(endpoint + '/' + c + '/' + m)
  })
  
  const results = await Promise.all(promises)
})
```

Since countries depend on the market, I don't know how I can wait everything to finish since the promises are inside the countries map and I can't dettach from it since it depends on it.

Any help on this?

Tried to add Promise.resolve() and return an array of promises and do promise.all again, but those promises are also never resolved.

Any help will be good, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `countries.map(async c => …)` already *does* return an array of promises. Just use `Promise.all` on that. No `Promise.resolve()` calls, no returning an array of promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the promises at the countries level. If you return the `Promise.all` and then do another `Promise.all` on the results of `countries.map`, that should help.

```
const countries = ['de', 'pt', 'en'];
const market = ['test1', 'test2'];

const prCountries = countries.map(c => {
  const promises = market.map(m => {
    return fetch(endpoint + '/' + c + '/' + m);
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
});

Promise.all(prCountries).then(x=> {
  // do stuff when all promises have resolved
});
```

Comment: Seems it worked fine, just one more thing, I want to continue on code if the promise fails, I don't care about it, the thing is when a promise fails it stops the execution and I don't reach the success

Comment: If the fetch fails I don't reach the Promise.all(prCountries) :(